# Link between two docker containers in a network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have a docker network between geoserver and postgres. When I do docker inspect `container name` I can see the two are linked. When I exec into the geoserver container I can ping the postgres container but when I try to connect to a postgres db from within the geoserver container I get an error

> psql: could not translate host name `postgres` to address: Name or service not known

Here is an example of my docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:

postgres:
  image: kartoza/postgis:9.5-2.2
geoserver:
  image: geonode/geoserver
  hostname: geonode-geoserver
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
  ports:
    - "8181:8080"
```

I know with docker networks the `/etc/hosts` file is not populated. How can I enable accessing the database from geoserver container.

Answer (score 0):

The `geoserver` service is probably starting before the `postgres` service is available.

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [defined network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#/user-defined-networks) for resolve names without links and use [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/depends-on) for postgres start before geoserver.

Answer (score 0):

in the geoserver service definition change:

- postgres:postgres

to:

- postgres:kartoza/postgis:9.5-2.2

You need to match the service name to the image name

Comment: how do you link a running container to an image ?.  Do we not use an image to create a container and then link containers

Comment: version: '2'
services:

postgres:
  image: kartoza/postgis:9.5-2.2
geoserver:
  image: geonode/geoserver
  hostname: geonode-geoserver
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
  ports:
    - "8181:8080"